# How will you extract 2 numbers and store them into a separate variable from string

Tags: javascript

How will you extract 2 numbers and store them into a separate variable from the string like "You have 5 pen and 16 books".

```
var string =  "You have 5 pen and 16 books";
string.replace(/\D/g,' ');
```

Comment: I know that everyone is understand his question what he is want to ask, if you know answer , then why are you guys are down voting his question

Comment: @Lokeshthakur It seems likely to be an X - Y question, that's why "unclear what asking".

Answer (score 5):

You can try with [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

> The `match()` method retrieves the result of matching a string against a *regular expression*.

and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert the returned array items to number in the following way:

```js
var string =  "You have 5 pen and 16 books";
var res = string.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
console.log(res);
```